# Python sqlite3 OperationalError in a simple table create

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

## here is the code

```
def __init__(self):
    self._db = sqlite3.connect("Reservation.db")
    self._db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    self._db.execute("create table if not exists Ticket(ID integer primary key autoincrement, Name text, Gender text, Order text)")#create a table called Ticket with 4 columns
    self._db.commit()
```

## the proplem

self._db.execute("create table if not exists Ticket(ID integer primary key autoincrement, Name text, Gender text, Order text)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Order": syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word in SQL. I suggest you find a different name, that isn't a reserved word (e.g., `order_text`) for the column. If you absolutely must use this name, you can escape it by surrounding it with double quotes (`"`):

```
self._db.execute("create table if not exists Ticket(ID integer primary key autoincrement, Name text, Gender text, \"Order\" text)
# Here -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^------^
```